# (C++) CURL_STATICLIB: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks, libcurl

I've installed and configured my curl library and linked it to MinGW through CodeBlocks. Everything went fine, but when I built the code, I get an error:

```
CURL_STATICLIB        No such file or directory
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[CURL_STATICLIB Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRwf4.png)

I've defined CURL_STATICLIB in #defines:
[CURL_STATICLIB in #defines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OauCv.png)

Also here's a build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in CurlTest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g CURL_STATICLIB -DCURL_STATICLIB -std=c++11 -lcurl -DCURL_STATICLIB -IC:\libs\curl\include -c C:\Users\ondre\OneDrive\Documents\Projects++\CurlTest\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe: error: CURL_STATICLIB: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

My compiler info:

```
MinGW gcc (GCC) 5.3.0
```

Comment: Your code isn't relevant to this error. The build log of the failing build is relevant. You'll find it in the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab) of the IDE. Replace the code with the build log or add the build log as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to replace it.

Comment: CodeBlocks isn't a compiler. It's an IDE. It affects in no way how your code is compiled. Post your actual compiler info (seems to be mingw32 g++ from the error).

Comment: I don't know if you mean this info but I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your failing compile command:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g CURL_STATICLIB -DCURL_STATICLIB -std=c++11 \
-lcurl -DCURL_STATICLIB -IC:\libs\curl\include \
-c C:\Users\ondre\OneDrive\Documents\Projects++\CurlTest\main.cpp-o obj\Debug\main.o
```

we can see that as well as adding `CURL_STATICLIB` to the preprocessor
defines (`-DCURL_STATICLIB`), you have also in fact added it to your
**Other compiler options** (`-g CURL_STATICLIB`). And since of course
the string `CURL_STATICLIB` is not a g++ option and does not
begin with `-`, g++ interprets it as the name of an input file
for the compilation, which explains your error.

Futhermore you have added `-lcurl` to your compile options,
indicating that your want to link `libcurl` with your program. This isn't
a compile option, it is a linkage option. The compiler will ignore it
and, if you have not also added it to your linker options, then your
program will fail to link once you have succeeded in compiling it.

To fix this, remove `-lcurl` from your compiler options and add it
to **Other linker options**

Comment: Thank you! it solved my problem. Marked as the right answer :)